# How to add marker to the googlemaps in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

This is my entire code(just a test page). It shows the map but not the marker. How can I make it show the marker?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map_canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map
          });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you haven't defined any variable `latLng` and you are using it in marker. So obviously your code will not work. First define the `latLng` and then use.

Define it something like this:

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463);//Your marker coordinates.
```

and then use it in your code like:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x8dSP/3520/

Comment: This works. Before posting my question I tried to define it but couldn't find the proper way to do it. 
Thanks for the help